# mySQL - PHP time = time pls 12 hours

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have a database (mySQL) with a time field. I want to write a simple line or two in my php script to add 12 hours to the time IF the time is less than 12:00:00

Please can anyone help (newbie!)

Kind regards.
Philip.

Comment: I only need to DISPLAY the new time - not write it to the database.,

Comment: How are you selecting and displaying the original value? Please show us your code.

Comment: It's better to do this in MySQL. This sounds like you are trying to format 12 hour to 24 hour time system? There are easy ready-to-use functions.

Comment: @PhilipBarrett see the sql fiddle demo link in my answer for a simple test.. you can play with it without having to run through your whole system :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use MySQL for that because it is faster and less to write :-)

This doesn't update the column but fetches the time according to your expectation.

Make sure to actually have time column as TIME/DATETIME type.

```
SELECT
  IF(HOUR(timecol) > 12,
    DATE_ADD(INTERVAL 12 HOUR, timecol),
    timecol
  ) AS new_timecol
FROM table
```

Also keep in mind:

```
1st of month, 23:30 o clock.

+ 12 hours = 

2nd of month, 11:30 o clock.
```

If you want to select the time in 24 hour format, there are flags which simply allow you to do so without adding 12 hours or something.

Comment: Cheers Dan... I'll give this a try! :)]

Comment: I think this is backwards.. it sounds like the OP wants to convert time that is < than 12 to have an additional 12 hours.

Comment: If so, he can change `>` to `<` and/or `DATE_ADD` to `DATE_SUB`, respectively.

Comment: @DanFromGermany i figured I'd let you know incase you wanted to add that to your answer... because the OP wouldn't know about the date_sub as opposed to date_add. but i guess he knows now from the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is check if it less than 12 then add an interval of 12 hours or else just put in the time like so :)

```
SELECT 
  CASE  
    WHEN timecol < '12:00:00' THEN ADDTIME(timecol, '12:00:00')
    WHEN timecol >= '12:00:00' THEN timecol
  END
FROM test
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a2824/3)

---

## EDIT:

with the newly provided information you should incorporate it into the original select like so.

```
SELECT ff_id, book_cancel, booking_date, 
       pax_number, room, name, tel_number, 
       email, voucher_type, voucher_number, notes,
       CASE  
           WHEN time < '12:00:00' THEN ADDTIME(time, '12:00:00')
           WHEN time >= '12:00:00' THEN time
       END AS time
FROM tables 
WHERE booking_date>= '" . date("Y-m-d") . "' 
ORDER BY booking_date ASC, time ASC
```

Comment: Problem is I already have a script addressing quite a few fields - and I don't know where to include this... Here's my script:
http://www.availabilities.co.uk/booking_script.txt

Comment: @PhilipBarrett looks like you need it to be in your original select. give me a second and I'll update with your query fixed

Comment: @PhilipBarrett ok I just edited.. I changed it to select the fields you need and instead of selecting the time column you do the case statement and give it the alias 'time' so that way it will work with the rest of your stuff.. try it out!

Comment: An error occurred searching the database!
Error Msg: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE  
           WHEN time < '12:00:00' THEN ADDTIME(time, '12:00:00')
        ' at line 5

Comment: Hi John...  It's still not happenning. Any ideas?

Comment: GENIUS... John. Thanks so much!!!   I've been trying to sort that for days without getting anywhere!

Comment: @PhilipBarrett of course! :) if you could throw an accepted check mark my way and maybe a +1 id greatly appreciate it.. i'll reciprocate :)